# Oracle (on server) - Excel connection

Tags: oracle, excel, odbc

I've linked a couple of Oracle XE 11G views to Excel. I can import those views via the ODBC wizard in Excel and it works fine like that. The only thing is that both Oracle and Excel are on the same local client computer.

I'd like to have the Oracle XE database on a server and have Excel on client computers and still be able to connect. To basicly view Oracle data from a server in Excel.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you see http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/how-to-query-oracle-from-excel-2007/? If that does not suit, you can query using ADODB and VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link below:

[Single-tier ODBC Driver for Oracle (Lite Edition)](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-oracle-st/)

This will allow your Excel application to access a remote Oracle database via ODBC

Kind regards,

Wez Dance

OpenLink Software, Inc.